# Why do formal mathematics courses teach vector,coordinate geometry and complex numbers separetely?

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, vectors, analytic-geometry

All books or courses have separate chapters or courses for vector,coordinate geometry and complex numbers.But Vector,coordinate geometry and complex numbers are closely related and can be integrated beautifully to be taught together for a better understanding.But why are these not taught together in an integrated way?Are there any concepts in one topic that is not included in the other which makes the teaching of the three topics separetely necessary?Or are these the same thing being taught in different ways?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: complex numbers are similar to vectors and the Cartesian plane, but they don't scale to **3D** in the same way. complex numbers don't have a **3D** counterpart where the other two do. Ok, they do, but it's really **4D**

Comment: "All books or courses have separate ..." That's an extremely bold claim.  Do you have any evidence to support that statement?

Comment: I think the more general question that you are touching upon here is *What happened to classical geometry?* We teach only the things that are absolutely necessary for certain classes.

Comment: @Bye_World MIT 18.02 teaches Vectors;18.04 teaches complex numbers and 18.725 teaches Analytical Geometry (Coordinate)...I can site many examples from my text books too...:-)

Comment: @tatan I was just being cheeky, but oh well: Here's a counterexample: The book [*Calculus* by Robert Adams](https://www.bookdepository.com/Calculus-Robert-Adams/9780321549280) has a chapter entitled "Vectors and Coordinate Geometry in 3-Space".   So there is at least one book that combines vectors and coordinate geometry.  I could probably find at least one book that has a chapter on all three if I were so inclined (which I'm not).

Comment: 18.725 is a course on *algebraic geometry*, an extremely advanced subject. It is not the place where coordinate geometry is introduced. 18.04 is a course on *complex analysis*, and it is by no means the first time that students are introduced to complex numbers. Vectors, coordinate geometry, and complex numbers are all typically introduced in precalculus courses.

Comment: @Bye_World Nice to learn that such a book exists...:-)

Comment: @littleO You can't expect MIT to provide introduction to basic topics... those are done in high school...:-)

Comment: Some topics in linear algebra deal with complex vectors. It's hard to imagine how the "complex" part of that topic and the "vector" part of that topic can be separately taught in separate courses or separate chapters of books.

Answer (score 4):

They are related, but not the same. For instance, while the complex numbers have some similar geometric properties as the plane, they also have additional structure: you can multiply and divide complex numbers in a non-ambiguous way, whereas this is not possible for vectors on the plane. $\mathbb{R}^2$ also has a different differential structure than $\mathbb{C}$. Every complex-differentiable function is not only also infinitely differentiable on its domain, it is equal to its Taylor series everywhere on its domain. On the other hand, there are plenty of examples of functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are only once differentiable.

Now, these fields are certainly related, and when studying the theory of complex variables one sometimes makes use of the underlying vector structure, and some basic knowledge of the algebraic properties of $\mathbb{C}$ is convenient when studying linear algebra, but they are separate enough as ideas that the modern teaching style makes sense. Further, combining these topics runs the risk of having a student believe that vectors are an inherently two-dimensional class of objects.